# Rails 3: How does "accepts_nested_attributes_for" work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

Consider the following association:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop
end
```

If

```
params[:product][:shop_attributes] = {"name" => "My Shop"}
```

and I do:

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
@product.save
```

a new shop with name "My Shop" is created and assigned to the `@product`, as expected.

However, I can't figure out what happens when `shop_attributes` contains some `id`, like:

```
params[:product][:shop_attributes] = {"id" => "20", "name" => "My Shop"}
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Shop with ID=20 for Product with ID=
```

**Question 1**

What does this means ?

**Question 2**

If this is the case, i.e. the `id` of the shop is known, and the shop with such `id` already exist, how should I create the `@product` such that this shop will be assigned to it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you're trying to figure out creating a new associated item vs. associating with an existing item.

For creating a new item, you seem to have it working.
When you passed the id in shop_attributes, it did not work, because it's looking up an association that doesn't exist yet.

If you're trying to associate with an existing item, you should be using the following:

```
params[:product][:shop_id] = "20"
```

This will assign the current product's shop to the shop with id 'shop_id'.  (Product should have a 'shop_id' column.)

Comment: Any idea how this works if a product has multiple shops? Like `params[:product][:shops_attributes] = {"0" => {"id" => "20", "name" => "My Shop"}, "1" => {...}}`? Thanks!

Comment: Using the `params[:product][:shop_id]` methodology, you can do: `params[:product][:shop_ids] = [20,23,27]`