# Cannot get nested form with a has_one association to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-one

I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :city
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This controller action:

```
   def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and this view:

```
<%= form_for :user,:url => users_path,:method => :post do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :city do |b| %>
    <%= b.collection_select :id,City.all,:id,:name %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to allow the user to select a city from the list of already added cities. I am trying to present him a select. The select part it works, but the generated html code for it, looks like this:

```
<select name="user[city][id]" id="user_city_id">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Notice that it's name doesn't have `attribute` anywhere. So, when I try to save it, I get this error:

```
City(#37815120) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#32969916)
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: there is some progress, I tried to change the fields_for to this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :city_attributes do |b| %>
    <%= b.collection_select :id,City.all,:id,:name %>
<% end %>
```

and now, the html seems to generate correctly. But I get this error now:

```
Couldn't find City with ID=1 for User with ID=
```

I have no idea what to do next.

EDIT2: overriding the `city_attributes=` method seems to work:

```
def city_attributes=(attribs)
    self.city = City.find(attribs[:id])
end
```

I don't know if it's the way to go, but it seems good.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this question that seems similar to yours :
[Rails 3: How does "accepts_nested_attributes_for" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485507/rails-3-how-does-accepts-nested-attributes-for-works)

Actually, since the Cities already exsit, I think there is no need for nested forms here.

Try Replacing

```
<%= f.fields_for :city_attributes do |b| %>
    <%= b.collection_select :id,City.all,:id,:name %>
<% end %>
```

With

```
<%= f.collection_select :city, City.all,:id,:name %>
```

**Updated afters comments**

Could you change your relationship with (and update database scheme accordingly)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

And then try using:

```
<%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all,:id,:name %>
```

Comment: Yeah, it was my first approach too. But this gives this error: `City(#37103820) expected, got String(#21183516)`. Because it will call the `.city` method, which expects a City instance.

Comment: Oops, just realised that you User won't have a city_id 

Could you change your relationship with (and update database scheme accordingly) 

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :city
    end
    
    class City < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :users
    end

And then try using:

    <%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all,:id,:name %>

Comment: Yes, I know that reversing the relationship works, I was just curious why nested forms only seem to work for creating new associations, and not for finding existing ones.

Comment: Nested forms does not only create new associations. It creates the associated objects. Thinking about it, you can not assign a new user to an existing city since a city `belongs_to :user` (eash city can thus have only one user). However, you could probably change your form so that it will create a new City with `user_id` = the new id and `name` = the selected one from a dropdown collecting names from existing cities with something similar to `<%= b.collection_select :name,City.all(:group => "name"),:name,:name %>`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a

`<%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all, :id, :name %>`

in your view and then add virtual attributes to your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def city_id(c_id)
    update_attribute(:city, City.find(c_id))
  end

  def city_id
    city.id
  end
end
```

This might not be very clean, since the associated City model is "saved" whenever assigning an ID to some_user.city_id. However, this solution keeps your controller and view nice and clean.

Note: you might also want to account for a blank ID being passed in to the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

<%= f.select(:city_id, City.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>

Comment: I get this error: `undefined method 'city.user_id' for #<User id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Comment: sorry, need to be 'user.city_id'

Comment: Still doesn't work. `undefined method 'user.city_id' for #<User id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Comment: I check this solution
<%= f.select(:city_id, City.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>

Comment: Did you add a `city_id` field in the User model?

Comment: But then, you'd have user have the `belongs_to` association.

Comment: class City no need any associations. You may use @user.city to get the city