# Mixing User fields with Profile fields in Rails 3 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Conceptually, is it possible to have a form in Rails that accepts input for both User **and** Profile fields? If so, how could I execute that? Do I need to set the `form_for` for both User and Profile?

The goal is to have two forms (one on the homepage and one at signup) that could potentially mix user/profile information when saved. FYI - here is how I add a user:

```
user = User.new
user.email = ""
user.password = ""
user.profile = Profile.new
user.profile.save
user.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should look into `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, addressed in the Rails docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

For more information, please look into:

- [This blog](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) discussing the usage.
- [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485507/rails-3-how-does-accepts-nested-attributes-for-work) addressing its usage in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested form, and a model with nested attributes to accomplish this. Follow the [Ryan Bates tutorial on Nested Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)